# How can I block all internet connections except the Microsoft Update website?

Tags: windows-xp, security, firewall, windows-update

I want download updates for Windows XP. Until all updates have been downloaded, my computer will be more exposed to hackers. How can I block all internet connections except those to/from the Microsoft Update website?

Also, what else should I do to prevent hackers from accessing my PC while updates are being downloaded and installed (there's a lot of them after a clean installation).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way to address this is to enable the windows firewall or put yourself behind a NAT router. This will disable incoming connections.  If your computer is exposed to hackers via outgoing connections, updating windows will not resolve the issue.  Otherwise, a firewall will correct the issue permanently with or without updates.

Comment: its first instalation - pc clean after disk format

Comment: Ok, so again, a firewall will work.

Comment: but if windows luck important updates hacker can access the PC right?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand the question.  If your computer is behind a firewall, particularly a router or other hardware device, a hacker should be unable to connect, let-alone breach; I recommend not browsing the internet, however, until fully patched.  No security-measures or firewall can prevent access when initiated by you, even if accidentally or unintentionally.